# Only display row if all CASE statement conditions are fullfilled

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f5b95d686757ea86831837f17423a496)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    date_offered VARCHAR (255),
    date_sold VARCHAR (255), 
    quantity_offered VARCHAR(255),
    quantity_sold VARCHAR(255),
    value_offered VARCHAR(255),
    value_sold VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sales
(id, campaign,
date_offered, date_sold,
quantity_offered, quantity_sold,
value_offered, value_sold
)
VALUES 
("1", "C001", "2019-02-06", "2019-02-10", "500", "600", "4000", "4800"),
("2", "C002", "2019-04-15", "2019-04-12", "400", "800", "3200", "6400"),
("3", "C003", "2019-06-23", "2019-03-19", "650", "700", "5200", "5600"),
("4", "C004", "2019-08-09", "2019-08-22", "250", "150", "1750", "1050"),
("5", "C005", "2019-11-12", "2020-01-15", "860", "450", "6020", "3150"),
("6", "C006", "2020-01-30", "2019-12-18", "130", "280", "1170", "2520"),
("7", "C007", "2020-02-17", "2019-11-23", "470", "400", "4230", "3600");
```

In the table above are several mistakes that I identify with the `CASE` statement in this query:

```
SELECT
id,
campaign,
(CASE WHEN DATE(date_offered) > DATE(date_sold) THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Date,
(CASE WHEN SUM(quantity_offered) < SUM(quantity_sold) THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Quantity,
(CASE WHEN SUM(value_offered)/SUM(quantity_offered) > 10 THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Price_01,
(CASE WHEN SUM(value_sold)/SUM(quantity_sold) > 7 THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Price_02
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1;
```

All this works exactly the way I need it.

---

Now, I want to modify the `result` of the query so only the `rows` that **contain at least one Error** remain in the result. 
 
If all values are o.k. the `row` should not be displayed:

```
id  campaign       Check_Date      Check_Quantity       Check_Price_01     Check_Price_02
1   C001            OK              Error                OK                 Error
2   C002            Error           Error                OK                 Error
3   C003            Error           Error                OK                 Error
6   C006            Error           Error                OK                 Error
7   C007            Error           OK                   OK                 Error
```

How do I have to change my query to achieve this?

Comment: Your logic is incorrect. Either filter out individual rows where the quantity or dates are incorrect, or filter entire groups where the _sums_ are incorrect. You cannot do both in one query.

Comment: `HAVING ('Error' IN (Check_Date, Check_Quantity, Check_Price_01, Check_Price_01));`, [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=aeed7b2d9188cecfd98b666c3572582e).

Comment: `group by 1` makes each row a group of 1. That means `sum` doesn't sum anything. You can eliminate the `group by` and simply write: `quantity_offered < quantity_sold`.

Comment: @Akina you should post your comment as answer.

Comment: Just an observation, you're grouping by a primary key, which by definition means that every group consists of only one row.

Comment: @RaekhVoid 3 identical answers is enough, 4th is excess I think. I simply demonstrate more clear synonim of multi-OR...

Comment: @Akina and the syntax is gorgeous

Comment: 2OP: I'd recommend NOT use duplicated output fields aliases...

Comment: @Akina: Thanks for the hint. It was a typo. I edited my question and the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution using `having` clause

```
SELECT
id,
campaign,
(CASE WHEN DATE(date_offered) > DATE(date_sold) THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Date,
(CASE WHEN SUM(quantity_offered) < SUM(quantity_sold) THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Quantity,
(CASE WHEN SUM(value_offered)/SUM(quantity_offered) > 10 THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Price_01,
(CASE WHEN SUM(value_sold)/SUM(quantity_sold) > 7 THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Price_02
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1
HAVING ('Error' IN (Check_Date, Check_Quantity, Check_Price_01, Check_Price_01));
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f9beb5f43ff29feb1da4c7d5b865925f

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT
id,
campaign,
(CASE WHEN DATE(date_offered) > DATE(date_sold) THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Date,
(CASE WHEN SUM(quantity_offered) < SUM(quantity_sold) THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Quantity,
(CASE WHEN SUM(value_offered)/SUM(quantity_offered) > 10 THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Price_01,
(CASE WHEN SUM(value_sold)/SUM(quantity_sold) > 7 THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Price_01
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1
HAVING Check_Date = "Error" 
OR Check_Quantity = "Error"
...
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
id,
campaign,
(CASE WHEN DATE(date_offered) > DATE(date_sold) THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Date,
(CASE WHEN SUM(quantity_offered) < SUM(quantity_sold) THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Quantity,
(CASE WHEN SUM(value_offered)/SUM(quantity_offered) > 10 THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Price_01,
(CASE WHEN SUM(value_sold)/SUM(quantity_sold) > 7 THEN "Error" ELSE "OK" END) AS Check_Price_02
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1
) t WHERE Check_Date = 'Error' OR Check_Quantity = 'Error' OR Check_Price_01 = 'Error' OR Check_Price_02 = 'Error';
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the results that "work exactly the way you need", it looks like you do not need SUM or GROUP BY, just a simple WHERE clause:

```sql
SELECT id
     , campaign
     , CASE WHEN DATE(date_offered) > DATE(date_sold)  THEN 'Error' ELSE 'OK' END AS Check_Date
     , CASE WHEN quantity_offered < quantity_sold      THEN 'Error' ELSE 'OK' END AS Check_Quantity
     , CASE WHEN value_offered / quantity_offered > 10 THEN 'Error' ELSE 'OK' END AS Check_Price_01
     , CASE WHEN value_sold / quantity_sold > 7        THEN 'Error' ELSE 'OK' END AS Check_Price_02
FROM sales
WHERE DATE(date_offered) > DATE(date_sold)
OR    quantity_offered < quantity_sold
OR    value_offered / quantity_offered > 10
OR    value_sold / quantity_sold > 7

-- returns rows 1, 2, 3, 6, 7
```